# How to set the array size with a function parameter?

Tags: c++, vector

I got a problem when I wrote some code for practice. It's about array size settings. I tried several different ways but they did not work.

Here is my code:

```
float mean(vector<float> numbers){
     int size = numbers.size();
     float dizi[size];
     float ort,toplam = 0.0;
     for(unsigned int i=0; i<numbers.size(); i++){
         dizi[i] = numbers[i];
         toplam += dizi[i];
     }

     ort = toplam / numbers.size();

     return ort;
 }
```

The errors I received were `"variable length array used"` and `"variable length arrays are a C99 feature"`. What is the solution?

Comment: Well, don't use variable length array? Why do you even need this array, you already have a nice collection to sum the numbers up.

Comment: use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Use `std::array` and/or `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: @Omid it's not known at compile time...

Answer (score 8):

You cannot set an array's size with a function parameter without a compiler that has a non-standard extension that allows [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). According to the C++ standard, array lengths MUST be a constant known when the program is compiled. Consider using another `std::vector` instead.

## However...

There doesn't seem to be a need for an array here. May I suggest something more like,

```
float mean(vector<float> numbers){
     int size=numbers.size();
     float ort,toplam=0.0;
     for(unsigned int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
         toplam+=numbers[i];
     }
     ort=toplam/numbers.size();
     return ort;
 }
```

or

```
float mean(vector<float> numbers){
     float toplam=0.0;
     for(float num: numbers){
         toplam+=num;
     }
     return toplam/numbers.size();
 }
```

or

```
float mean(vector<float> numbers){
     return std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0f)/numbers.size();
 }
```

?

[Documentation for `std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

In addition, as noted in the comments, consider passing `numbers` in as a constant reference (`float mean(const vector<float> & numbers)`) to eliminate unnecessary copying without risk of accidentally changing `numbers`.

Comment: indeed, no reason to have `dizi`.

Comment: And even pass vector by const ref instead of by value.

Comment: how could i think. Thanks